# Python OpenCV not reading this file properly?

Tags: python, opencv

This opencv program isn't reading the file that i've set it to read? it just displays a screenshot of the sidebar when i run it, it doesn't display the file properly. It saves the file fine.

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import time

img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Downloads/face_recognition_examples-master/img/known/Bill Gates.jpg')
cv2.imshow("image", img)
time.sleep(20)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to save this file where Bill Gates.jpg exists.